# Reduce to 53 class in column R

Tags: r, dataset

I have column in dataset with 66 class. I want to reduce to 53 class where top 52 class will have their name and for rest I want to set as 'Others'. I was able to find top 52 class with most frequency but I'm not sure how can I set 'Others' to rest 14 class.

Column:

```
dept Att Jon_sat
 A    Y    2
 C    N    1
 D    N    4
 .    .    .
 .    .    .
 AB   N    3
```

```
data %>%
  group_by(dept) %>%
  summarise(n()) %>%
  top_n(53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `fct_lump_n` from `forcats`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
data %>%
    mutate(dept = fct_lump_n(dept, n = 52))
#     dept
#1      s
#2     TT
#3      H
#4      I
#5      C
#6      j
#7     DD
#8     BB
#9     UU
#10     h
#11    DD
#12 Other
#13     h
#14 Other
#15     K
#16     u
#17 Other
#18     u
#19     h
#20    XX
#...
```

---

If we use the OP's method, one option is to `replace` the original 'dept' based on the values in 'dept'  extracted after the `top_n`

```
d1 <- data %>%
    group_by(dept) %>%
    summarise(n()) %>%
    top_n(53) %>%
    pull(dept)
data %>%
    mutate(dept = replace(dept, !dept %in% d1, 'Others'))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(dept = sample(c(letters, LETTERS, paste0(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
        500, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey it's just returning me dept in desc order and count with all 66 class. I want to update my original dataframe(Please check updated ques)  where just top 52 should have their name and rest should be name 'Others'

Comment: It's giving me this warning

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "Others") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```
I guess it's making NA instead of Others

Comment: @Chris_007 Witih `fct_lump_n`, I am not getting any warning even on `factor` column

Comment: I used OP's method where I'm getting that warning!

Comment: @Chris_007 i can't reproduce that with the data in my post

Comment: Hey got it! I was able to do that from your 1st solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chris_007 in second soluton with `reeplace`, you need to cnovert to `character`  class